# Django queryset for many to many relation

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I can't understand how I should get queryset for groups, that contains user, I've tried `__set`, `prefetch_select`, but still without result.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    Member_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member', blank=True, related_name="Member_list")

class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

I need get all Groups, where `Member.objects.filter(user==request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

You should start querying from the user.

Try this

```
user = request.user
groups = user.group_set.all()
```

Comment: It returns empty list, but my user have at last 1 group, i checked.

Comment: member = user.member_set.all() - returns 1 group,    groups = user.group_set.all() returns empty list

Answer (score 0):

There was circle in my db model, group_set goes other way, thats why it returns empty.
With related_name it works correct:

```
u.Member_list.all()
```